# zend db select join help

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, select, join

so I have this code:

```
$sql = new Zend_Db_Select($db);
$sql->from("j");
$sql->join("k","k.id = j.id",array());
echo $sql;
```

which results in the query:

```
SELECT `j`.* FROM `j` INNER JOIN `k` ON k.id = j.id
```

but I don't just want j.*

I also want k.*

how do I specify zend_db_select for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter for join() is `columns` for select. You have passed an empty array.

```
$sql = new Zend_Db_Select($db);
$sql->from('j');
$sql->join('k','k.id = j.id',array());
echo $sql;
```

Note: for this condition `k.id = j.id` you should use LEFT JOIN(->joinLeft(...))

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the columns in the from method.

```
$sql->from(array("j" => "j", array("j.*" , "k.*");
```

Honestly I am not entirely sure but the Zend Documentation says so :)

Answer (score 0):

if you also want `k.*`, I think you should have
`$sql->join("k","k.id = j.id");`, without that `array()` as the third parameter.
From what I know, that third parameter specifies the columns to be selected from `k` and since you passed an empty array I'm guessing you override that default `k.*`

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly tells the join that you want no columns returned for `k` when you pass an empty array to it. Instead use:

```
$sql = new Zend_Db_Select($db);
$sql->from('j');
$sql->joinLeft('k','k.id = j.id');
echo $sql;
```

That should produce what you want I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql=new Zend_Db_Select($db);
$sql->from('j',array(
//here fields you want to get from 'j' Ex. 'j.id'
));
$sql->join('k',
// here your condition
'k.id = j.id',
//here the fields you need from 'k'
array(
//now the array is empty!!You need to specify needed fields.
//Or just remove it.Defaults is "k.*"!

));
```